# PSQL - Group by with sum and a random value from the group

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have this table

```
type | child_id  | status
-----------------------------------
1    | a         | completed
1    | b         | failed
1    | a         | completed
1    | c         | completed
-----------------------------------
2    | a         | failed
2    | b         | failed
```

I want to group the values by type, get the count of different statuses, and also get any value from the child_id, to get such a result.

```
type | child_id  | completed   | failed
-----------------------------------------
1    | b         | 3           | 1
2    | a         | 0           | 2
```

*For type 1, child_id a, b or c is acceptable; and a or b for type 2.*

I can use this to all the columns except child_id

```
 SELECT type, 
   sum(case when status  = 'completed' then 1 else 0 end) as completed,
   sum(case when  status  = 'failed' then 1 else 0 end) as failed
 from mytable
 group by type;
```

Just need to figure out if there is a way to get the child_id in there as well, without doing a join.

Comment: if you are grouped by `type`, you can get `child_id` only using `max(child_id)`, `min(child_id)`, `count(child_id)` or etc. Because for type =1 you have many `child_id` values. How can DB know what value you need.

Comment: I was thinking something like random(child_id). I should've used non-numerics, because my data isn't a number. I've updated it now. If it were numbers, I could've used max or count. Thanks

Comment: `max` or `min` works on text types too.  But if you have million or billion records performance maybe little decreasing. PostgreSQL has `first_value` and `last_value` functions too. Try use it.